# ajax auto-complete pass additional value

Tags: ajax, autocomplete

I have been working with ajax auto-complete, here i need to pass an additional variable from Source to select of jquery ui,  Iam using getJSON method , and i need to get value of the selected option from suggested dropdown ..here is the code sample.

```
$("#searchkw").autocomplete({

    source: function(req, add) {
        $.getJSON("/admin/news_master/searchkeyword", req, function(data) {
           var suggestions = [];

            $.each(data, function(i, val) {
                suggestions.push(val.relational_keyword);
            }); 
            add(suggestions);
        });
    },

    select: function(e, ui) {
        var keywrd = ui.item.value;
        span = $("<span>").text(keywrd).attr({value: itemId});

        span.appendTo("#relationalBox");
        $("#searchkw").val("").css("top", 2);
        return false;

    }, 
});
```

Can any one Please help .!!

Answer (score 0):

This function to push selected value:

```
 var submitAutocompleteForm = function (event, ui) {
        var $input = $(this);
        $input.val(ui.item.label);

        var $form = $input.parent("form:first");
        $form.submit();
    }
```

And pass it into select

```
 select: submitAutocompleteForm
```

Or you could just take it like `ui.item.label`